# ipython security lib missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Greeetings,

per instructions for IPython, I am supposed to be able to run this import when coding:

```
from IPython.lib.security import passwd_check
```

I have IPython 8.8.0 installed as part of a jupyter install.

however, when I attempt to run this library, it reports:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.lib.security'
```

what am I missing?
THanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the `IPython.lib.security` is not present anymore in version 8.x.

If you are using version `7x` you should be able to import it with.

I was able to import successfully:

```
from IPython.lib.security import passwd_check
```

on my `7.x` version

```
IPython.__version__
'7.25.0'
```

if you want to lower version you can try:

```
%pip install IPython==7.25.0
```